# Flex Builder 3 IDE - Mouse Wheel Scrolling

Tags: ide, mouse, flexbuilder

Currently when I am working in the source code view of the Flex Builder 3 IDE my mouse scroll wheel does not scroll the window up and down.

Is it possible to enable this functionality somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, this is just a work around, 
Get flash builder 4.x and point the sdk to 3.x